# Add x number of spaces between the letters of a string in Java?

Tags: java

I need to recieve a integer and have it print out that number of spaces in between the letters of a name. Right now I have it printing out one space.

```
public static void printLongName(int spaces){
String name 
char[] letter = name.toCharArray(); 
for(int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++)
System.out.print(" " + letter[i]);
System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void printLongName(String name, int numOfSpacesBetweenLetters) {
  StringBuffer sbSpace = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i <= numOfSpacesBetweenLetters; i++) {
    sbSpace.append(" ");
  }

  char[] letter = name.toCharArray(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(sbSpace + letter[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `System.out.format()`

```
    System.out.format("%10c", letter[i]);
```

update

```
   int spaces=10;
   String name ="aaaaaaaa"; 
   char[] letter = name.toCharArray(); 
   for(int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++)
       System.out.format("%10c", letter[i]);
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: c != java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

```
//System.out.print(" " + letter[i]);
//System.out.print(getSpace(10) + letter[i]);like this you can


public String getSpace(int count)
{
  String space="";
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        space+=" ";
   return space;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for something like this:

```
System.out.format("[%13s]%n", "");  // prints "[             ]" (13 spaces)
System.out.format("[%1$3s]%n", ""); // prints "[   ]" (3 spaces)
```

This regular expression will allow you to add your spaces appropriately.

Comment: You can concatenate your variable to add it into this regex so that it will automatically add these spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need build the space string first with parameter input. Please look at below code:

```
    public static void printLongName(int spaces){
        String name = "hello";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String spaceStr = "%"+spaces+"c";
        char[] letter = name.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                sb.append(letter[i]);
            } else {
                sb.append(String.format(spaceStr, letter[i]));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printLongName(4);
    }
```

Update some code.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a string with spaces:

```
String nameWithSpaces(String name, int spaces) {
    StringBuilder sbname = new StringBuilder(name);
    String spaces = String.valueOf(new char[spaces]).replace("\0", " ");
    for (int i=1; i < sbname.length(); i += spaces.length()+1)
        sbname.insert(i, spaces);
    return sbname.toString();
}
```